# Make jest globally available in storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, storybook

I am using `@storybook/react` 6 in a `create-react-app` project.

I have thousands of tests and mocks for all my stores/objects and so on.

These mocks make use of `jest.fn()`.

I would like to reuse these mocks in my storybook stories but it says `jest is not defined` which makes sense.

I am wondering if there is an easy way to make jest globally available when running storybook.

Currently I am adding `import jest from 'jest-mock'` in every mock file that I use but I am wondering if there is a better solution.

Example:

`test.stories.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';

export default {
  title: 'Test'
};

export Test = () => <button onClick={jest.fn()}>Test</button>;
```

Will compile but won't run -> `jest is not defined` error

```
import React from 'react';
import jest from 'jest-mock';

export default {
  title: 'Test'
};

export Test = () => <button onClick={jest.fn()}>Test</button>;
```

Works fine but I would like to avoid having to import `jest-mock` everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ensure the mock will be available in all your stories by adding the following lines to the `preview.js` file in your project's `.storybook` folder:

```
import jest from 'jest-mock';
window.jest = jest;
```

From the [Storybook docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/overview#configure-story-rendering):

> Use preview.js for global code (such as CSS imports or JavaScript
> mocks) that applies to all stories.

Comment: added `import jest from 'jest-mock';` to `preview.js` but it does not work

Comment: Tried it again and it didn't work for me either; sorry; I seem to have misremembered how it works. The following, though not pretty, seems to get the job done:

In preview.js:
`import jest from 'jest.mock'`
`window.jest = jest`

Comment: Edited my answer to include more accurate information.

Comment: Thanks that works ! I guess I never understood that you could set `window` properties inside `preview.js`.

Comment: getting error Type 'typeof import("node_modules/jest-mock/build/index")' is missing the following properties from type 'typeof jest': autoMockOff, autoMockOn, clearAllMocks, createMockFromModule, and 38 more.ts(2740)
namespace jest