# How to use Jest mocks in Code run by Storybook using React 17

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, storybook

We have a React 17 codebase that has a ton of functions that generate mock data type save, so we can re-use them in different unit tests run by Jest.

```
export const createMockProject = (
    overwrites: Partial<Project> = {}
): Project => ({
    id: 'PROJECT_ID',
    name: 'PROJECT_NAME',
    transfer: jest.fn(), // mock method. Not real code, just to show the schema
    ...overwrites,
});
```

For methods, we use jest.fn(). We want to re-use those mocks in Storybook, and figured we could just set Jest globally so that when code executed in storybook that calls jest.fn() actually never calls jest.

```
// inside .storybook/preview.ts

// Initialize global jest.fn override
window.jest = {
    fn: ((fnc: any) => fnc) as any,
};
```

That is a similar approach to just making `jest-mock` globally available, as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64349461/make-jest-globally-available-in-storybook).

The problem is that either way, [React checks for jest being defined](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v17.0.0/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.new.js#L1251) when reconciling, and throws console errors about things not being wrapped in act, which hinders any Developer to properly keep an eye on error logs while developing storybook stories.

```
TextField.tsx:171 Warning: An update to XComponent inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

act(() => {
  /* fire events that update state */
});
/* assert on the output */
```

I saw this `__DEV__` flag (see linked React code) picked up by Jest, but

- to me it is not clear what it is for, it just [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060295/jest-global-variable-example#comment116580106_57684993) like an [example](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration)
- setting it to false in the storybook setup file had no effect
- even if it worked, side effects by toggling it are not clear

I appreciate advice in how to tackle this.